# Start and stop application within python using the RPi GPIO?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

I'm using this python script:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import subprocess
from time import sleep

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)

try:  
    while True:
        if GPIO.input(4):
            GPIO.output(25, 1)
            subprocess.call("/script/start.sh", shell=True)
        else:
            GPIO.output(25, 0)
            subprocess.call("/script/stop.sh", shell=True)
        sleep(0.2)

finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

(Without subprocess) when I press the button (GPIO 4) an LED goes on, press it again and it's off. Works great. I'm currently using 2 scripts to start and stop an application. Those work fine when used outside of Python. When I try to implement the subprocess stuff things start to go wonky.

The scripts are:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILENAME=$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M")
rec -c 2 -b 24 -r 48000 -C 320.99 /mnt/usb/${FILENAME}.mp3
exit
```

and

```
#!/bin/bash
reco=`pidof -s rec`
kill $reco
exit
```

The process will be started, and it'll keep running, but the python script won't shut it down unless I hit ctrl+c, defeating the point of using the GPIO switch.

What I want to achieve is:

```
switch = high -> application starts
switch = low -> application stops
```

Wait/loop so I can start recording again if I press the switch.

How can I get this working properly?

Comment: Can you post the contents of `start.sh` and `stop.sh`?

Comment: #!/bin/bash
    FILENAME=$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M")
    rec -c 2 -b 24 -r 48000 -C 320.99 /mnt/usb/${FILENAME}.mp3
    exit

and

    #!/bin/bash
    reco=`pidof -s rec`
    kill $reco
    exit

Comment: consider editing your question with the content of your bash scripts. So others can help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're trying to kill the process you start in `start.sh`. This is what I recommend:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import signal
import subprocess
import os
from time import sleep

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)

rec_proc = None
try:  
    while True:
        if GPIO.input(4):
            GPIO.output(25, 1)
            if rec_proc is None:
                rec_proc = subprocess.Popen("/script/start.sh",
                           shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
        else:
            GPIO.output(25, 0)
            if rec_proc is not None:
                os.killpg(rec_proc.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
                rec_proc = None
        sleep(0.2)

finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Tried it and it spawns infinite rec processes until I manually kill the script. The spawned rec processes keep running in the background. I tried both the scipt as well as calling the rec process directly. It also won't respond to low voltage (switch off).

I'll have a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22690318/2797222) answer and see if that works for me.

Thanks!

Comment: @Sonof8-Bits thanks for the feedback. I have edited my answer to only create a new process if one isn't already running. HTH. Also I think it is a good idea to not use `start.sh` and to call `rec` directly from your python script.

Comment: Nailed it!! Only need to add `import signal` so signal.SIGTERM works. It now does exactly what I wanted to get done. Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Here's a picture of the working prototype!  :D 

[imgur](http://i.imgur.com/NXLE22B.jpg)

From left to right:
Input volume and VU meter. USB (flash drive) slot for recording, and a momentary button to safely eject the USB. Activity LED (constant = recording, slow blink is USB mounted ok, fast blink means USB is unmounted). Filetype switch for WAV or MP3 and last but not least the record button.

Thanks again for your time and help. I feel I learned a lot about python since these first steps.